# Is there a way to prevent quaternions from misbehaving?

Tags: transform, game-engine, quaternions

I am working on a game engine, and I ran into this problem when creating a position rotation scale component. The position and scale work just fine, but when I recalculate the rotation quaternion it will invert itself (i.e. point in the opposite direction). What we do is simple - 
Whenever the parent quaternion is changed:

- We rotate the parent accordingly - Fine
- We calculate the child's local rotation (relative to parent) - Fine
- We multiply the parent rotation by the child's local rotation - Not fine.

What we are doing is literally (q2/q1)*q2 -> q2*q1^-1*q2

I am using the http://www.technologicalutopia.com/sourcecode/xnageometry/quaternion.cs.htm implementation, where multiplying quaternions will rotate the first by the second, and dividing does the inverse.

I have spent weeks on this problem, so any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Please show us the actual algorithms you are using instead of just giving us worded descriptions of them.  E.g., not at all sure what you mean by q1/q2.

Comment: I have changed it now :)

Comment: I took a look at that link, and have concluded the following:  Quaternions are in a right-handed Hamilton convention (e.g., matching MATLAB), The Divide method does q1*q2^-1, and the Concatenate method does q2*q1. So can you explain in more detail what you are trying to do with that last step?

Comment: P.S. Also, the ToMatrix method reveals that a Left Chain convention is used.  I.e., the rotation operation vnew = q * v * q^-1 has the unmodified quaternion on the left side. Typically used for rotating a vector within the same coordinate frame (e.g., matching MATLAB Robotics Toolbox)

Comment: I looked some more, and it appears there may be an error in the CreateFromRotationMatrix method. It returns the conjugate of what I expected in one of my spot checks. That would give the opposite rotation. Are you using that method?

Comment: And, can you explain your phrase "invert itself"? If all of the quaternion element signs change, then the final rotated position will be the same, and this is still a valid result. Is that is all that is going on in your case? Or something else?

Comment: I am not unfortunately, but I am multiplying so there could be something wrong there

Comment: Also I realised I did my maths wrong, but it still returns the same issue.

Comment: No, the quaternion rotates 180 degrees on any axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be an error in the CreateFromRotationMatrix method code in the link you posted. My calculations show that all of the difference calculations have the wrong sign. The corrected code would be this, changes where annotated:

```
public static Quaternion CreateFromRotationMatrix(Matrix matrix)
{
    double num8 = (matrix.M11 + matrix.M22) + matrix.M33;
    Quaternion quaternion;
    if (num8 > 0.0)
    {
        double num = (double)sqrt((double)(num8 + 1.0));
        quaternion.W = num * 0.5;
        num = 0.5 / num;
        quaternion.X =-(matrix.M23 - matrix.M32) * num; // -
        quaternion.Y =-(matrix.M31 - matrix.M13) * num; // -
        quaternion.Z =-(matrix.M12 - matrix.M21) * num; // -
        return quaternion;
    }
    if ((matrix.M11 >= matrix.M22) && (matrix.M11 >= matrix.M33))
    {
        double num7 = (double)sqrt((double)(((1.0 + matrix.M11) - matrix.M22) - matrix.M33));
        double num4 = 0.5 / num7;
        quaternion.X = 0.5 * num7;
        quaternion.Y = (matrix.M12 + matrix.M21) * num4;
        quaternion.Z = (matrix.M13 + matrix.M31) * num4;
        quaternion.W =-(matrix.M23 - matrix.M32) * num4; // -
        return quaternion;
    }
    if (matrix.M22 > matrix.M33)
    {
        double num6 = (double)sqrt((double)(((1.0 + matrix.M22) - matrix.M11) - matrix.M33));
        double num3 = 0.5 / num6;
        quaternion.X = (matrix.M21 + matrix.M12) * num3;
        quaternion.Y = 0.5 * num6;
        quaternion.Z = (matrix.M32 + matrix.M23) * num3;
        quaternion.W =-(matrix.M31 - matrix.M13) * num3; // -
        return quaternion;
    }
    double num5 = (double)sqrt((double)(((1.0 + matrix.M33) - matrix.M11) - matrix.M22));
    double num2 = 0.5 / num5;
    quaternion.X = (matrix.M31 + matrix.M13) * num2;
    quaternion.Y = (matrix.M32 + matrix.M23) * num2;
    quaternion.Z = 0.5 * num5;
    quaternion.W =-(matrix.M12 - matrix.M21) * num2; // -

    return quaternion;

}
```

A sample run with a MATLAB mex file (qstuff) as a driver:

```
>> q2
q2 =
   0.531932290454131  -0.391764141068189   0.538459173155997   0.523097137240767
>> qstuff('CreateFromRotationMatrix',qstuff('ToMatrix',q2))
ans =
   0.531932290454131   0.391764141068189  -0.538459173155998  -0.523097137240767
>> qstuff('CreateFromRotationMatrixNew',qstuff('ToMatrix',q2))
ans =
   0.531932290454131  -0.391764141068189   0.538459173155998   0.523097137240767
```

The original code doesn't reproduce the quaternion, but the corrected code does.